# HighCharts Pattern-fill Diagonal pattern with solid lines

Tags: javascript, css, highcharts

I'm trying to accomplish a diagonal line pattern that contains solid lines with this strokeWidth value. This is what I've come up with so far but I can't seem to get the correct d-path:

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    type: 'area'
  },

  title: {
    text: 'Pattern fill plugin demo'
  },

  xAxis: {
    categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
  },

  plotOptions: {
    area: {
      fillColor: {
        pattern: {
          path: {
            d: 'M 0 0 L 25 25 M 24 -1 L 26 1 M -1 24 L 1 26',
            strokeWidth: 9
          },
          width: 25,
          height: 25,
          opacity: 0.2
        }
      }
    }
  },

  series: [{
    data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6],
    color: '#88e',
    fillColor: {
      pattern: {
        color: '#11d'
      }
    }
  }, {
    data: [null, null, null, null, null, 43.1, 95.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4],
    color: '#e88',
    fillColor: {
      pattern: {
        color: '#d11'
      }
    }
  }]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/pattern-fill.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="height: 400px; max-width: 800px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

If you take a look at that example, there are breaks in the lines. What do I need to change in order to get a solid diagonal line throughout? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Update: I was able to acheive the style I wanted with `d: 'M 0 0 L 25 25 M -5 20 L 5 30 M 20 -5 L 30 5'`